# Arranging auxiliary tasks for a Haskell project

Tags: haskell

There are some repetitive auxiliary tasks that I usually have to run when developing or testing a project. For example: downloading some data, setting up the database, cleaning the logs, etc. In Ruby land, they are handled by `rake` while other languages prefer `make` or something else (tasks occasionally depend on other tasks, so we may occasionally need one task to perform subtasks that it depends on).

So, **is there some conventional way to organize those tasks in a Haskell project?**

I would assume that `cabal` could be used for that, but not all of those auxiliary tasks are about running Haskell code: sometimes it's just a case of performing `rm -r logs/*.log` or downloading some data with `wget` or `curl`. Would it make sense to make cabal's `test` target depend on other cabal targets that, ugh, run shell scripts/commands from Haskell code? (If it's possible to have dependent targets in cabal at all?)

Alternatively, I could use `make`, but would "an average haskeller" (an "outside" project contributor, for example) find that intuitive? I believe one would first try `cabal test` before discovering that it requires setting up the database for the testing first, then running a whole chain of other tasks. Would one notice a `Makefile` in the first place?

I couldn't find any recipes for handling those auxiliary tasks in Haskell project around.

Comment: Note that `make` is not usually present on Windows. (But then again, neither is `wget` or `curl` or similar.) Remember, not every platform is Unix.

Answer (score 2):

As long as I know, there's no de facto standard tool in Haskell project.

But recently I heard [Shake](http://shakebuild.com/), a monadic build system written in Haskell.

Comment: Shake looks big for my tiny project, but I'll keep it in mind when working on something bigger. I think I'll stick with make for now. Thanks for the tip!